# Как скрыть определённые разделители(QSplitter) между QDockWidget в QMainWIndow PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyqt6, qdockwidget

Мне надо скрыть разделители между определёнными QDockWidget.

ChatGPT предлагает искать разделители в QDockWidget.

```
# Получаем QDockWidget, к которому принадлежит разделитель
dock_widget = ...  # Замените на ваш QDockWidget

# Находим все разделители внутри QDockWidget
splitters = dock_widget.findChildren(QSplitter)

# Применяем стиль к каждому разделителю
for splitter in splitters:
    splitter.setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle { background-color: transparent; }")
```

Но почему то у меня не в QMainWidow не в QDockWidget ни каких разделителей не находит.
А если устанавливать через styleSheet, то там нельзя применить к определённому QDockWidget-у, а только к QMainWindow

```
self.setStyleSheet(f"""
                QMainWindow::separator {{
                    width: 0px;
                }}
                """)
```

И стиль применяется ко всем разделителям в QMainWidow, а мне надо скрыть только те которые относятся к определённому QDockWidget.